# why it is true that $F[\sqrt{a}] = F[\sqrt{b}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $\operatorname{char}(F) \neq 2.$ Suppose $a,b \in F$ are not squares, and let $E = F(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}).$ why if we assume that $[E : F] = 2,$ why it is true that $F[\sqrt{a}] = F[\sqrt{b}]?$

Any clarification will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: by Tower Law they are both field extensions of $F$ with degree 2. So $E=F[\sqrt{a}]=F[\sqrt{b}]$.

Comment: It is an application of a general theorem of linear algebra: for any $k$-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, any $k$-dimensional subspace is equal to the whole space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because they're both ($F(\sqrt{a}), F(\sqrt{b})$) equal to the field $E$.

You have for example $2=[E:F]=[E:F(\sqrt{a})][F(\sqrt{a}):F]$ and since $[F(\sqrt{a}):F]$ must be $2$, the term $[E:F(\sqrt{a})]$ must be $1$ giving you $F(\sqrt{a})=E$.